how to extract the keys from dict in python polars string column
i want to extract the keys from dict of string column "C". keys will be different in all rows
df3 = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "b", "a", "c","a","c","a","b","b"], 
   "B": [23,45,60,50,56,44,34,30,97], 
   "C": ["{'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pattern2':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['abc','score1']}",
        "{'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pattern4':['df','text2']}",
        "{'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pattern6':['gh','text1'],'pattern7':['gh','text1']}",
        "{'pattern8':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pattern10':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern11':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern12':['a','score1'],'pattern13':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pattern5':['df','text1']}"]
})

need to extract the keys from string column "C" which is dict .
shape: (9, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C                                                                 ┆ KEYS                                 │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                                                               ┆ ---                                  │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ str                                                               ┆ list[str]                            │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ 23  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pattern2':['df','text1']}             ┆ ["pattern1", "pattern2"]             │
│ b   ┆ 45  ┆ {'pattern3':['abc','score1']}                                     ┆ ["pattern3"]                         │
│ a   ┆ 60  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pattern4':['df','text2']}             ┆ ["pattern1", "pattern4"]             │
│ c   ┆ 50  ┆ {'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pattern6':['gh','text1'],'pattern7':[ ┆ ["pattern5", "pattern6", "pattern7"] │
│     ┆     ┆ 'gh','text1']}                                                    ┆                                      │
│ a   ┆ 56  ┆ {'pattern8':['a','score1']}                                       ┆ ["pattern8"]                         │
│ c   ┆ 44  ┆ {'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pattern10':['df','text1']}            ┆ ["pattern9", "pattern10"]            │
│ a   ┆ 34  ┆ {'pattern11':['a','score1']}                                      ┆ ["pattern11"]                        │
│ b   ┆ 30  ┆ {'pattern12':['a','score1'],'pattern13':['df','text1']}           ┆ ["pattern12", "pattern13"]           │
│ b   ┆ 97  ┆ {'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pattern5':['df','text1']}             ┆ ["pattern3", "pattern5"]             │
└─────┴─────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘



You can use some regular expression-based replacement and parse out the remainder. One approach would extracting the keys with a pattern that anchors on the quotes and the colon. Then strip out the quotes and colon that are left over.
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df3 = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "b", "a", "c","a","c","a","b","b"], 
   "B": [23,45,60,50,56,44,34,30,97], 
   "C": ["{'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pattern2':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['abc','score1']}",
        "{'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pattern4':['df','text2']}",
        "{'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pattern6':['gh','text1'],'pattern7':['gh','text1']}",
        "{'pattern8':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pattern10':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern11':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern12':['a','score1'],'pattern13':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pattern5':['df','text1']}"]
})

print(
    df3.with_columns(
        KEYS=col('C').str.extract_all(r"'(\w+\d+)':").list.eval(pl.element().str.strip_chars("':"))
    ),
    # shape: (9, 4)
    # ┌─────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
    # │ A   ┆ B   ┆ C                               ┆ KEYS                            │
    # │ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                             ┆ ---                             │
    # │ str ┆ i64 ┆ str                             ┆ list[str]                       │
    # ╞═════╪═════╪═════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
    # │ a   ┆ 23  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern1", "pattern2"]        │
    # │ b   ┆ 45  ┆ {'pattern3':['abc','score1']}   ┆ ["pattern3"]                    │
    # │ a   ┆ 60  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern1", "pattern4"]        │
    # │ c   ┆ 50  ┆ {'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern5", "pattern6", "patt… │
    # │ a   ┆ 56  ┆ {'pattern8':['a','score1']}     ┆ ["pattern8"]                    │
    # │ c   ┆ 44  ┆ {'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern9", "pattern10"]       │
    # │ a   ┆ 34  ┆ {'pattern11':['a','score1']}    ┆ ["pattern11"]                   │
    # │ b   ┆ 30  ┆ {'pattern12':['a','score1'],'p… ┆ ["pattern12", "pattern13"]      │
    # │ b   ┆ 97  ┆ {'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern3", "pattern5"]        │
    # └─────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
)

Another approach involves using replace to remove any characters/character patterns you want to ignore. Then split on the remaining comma.
print(
    df3.with_columns(
        KEYS=col('C').str.replace_all(r"\{|\}|'|\[.+?\]|:", '').str.split(',')
    ),
    # shape: (9, 4)
    # ┌─────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
    # │ A   ┆ B   ┆ C                               ┆ KEYS                            │
    # │ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                             ┆ ---                             │
    # │ str ┆ i64 ┆ str                             ┆ list[str]                       │
    # ╞═════╪═════╪═════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
    # │ a   ┆ 23  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern1", "pattern2"]        │
    # │ b   ┆ 45  ┆ {'pattern3':['abc','score1']}   ┆ ["pattern3"]                    │
    # │ a   ┆ 60  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern1", "pattern4"]        │
    # │ c   ┆ 50  ┆ {'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern5", "pattern6", "patt… │
    # │ a   ┆ 56  ┆ {'pattern8':['a','score1']}     ┆ ["pattern8"]                    │
    # │ c   ┆ 44  ┆ {'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern9", "pattern10"]       │
    # │ a   ┆ 34  ┆ {'pattern11':['a','score1']}    ┆ ["pattern11"]                   │
    # │ b   ┆ 30  ┆ {'pattern12':['a','score1'],'p… ┆ ["pattern12", "pattern13"]      │
    # │ b   ┆ 97  ┆ {'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pa… ┆ ["pattern3", "pattern5"]        │
    # └─────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

)

